Can Cloud Function HTTP Trigger Logging other info Excluding Http Response
I am new to cloud function HTTP trigger,
I wrote a simple function for:
import functions_framework
import logging

@functions_framework.http
def cr_trigger(request):
    """HTTP Cloud Function.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): The request object.
        <https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#incoming-request-data>
    Returns:
        The response text, or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using `make_response`
        <https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.make_response>.
    """
    logging.info(f'START TO PROCESS THE API RESPONSE')
    request_json = request.get_json(silent=True)
    logging.info(f'request_json {request_json}')
    return request_json

And when I test and trigger the CF, it does not log out the message for START TO PROCESS THE API RESPONSE is this expected or is there any way I can logging other thing out?
Thanks!

Where do you expect to see the logs?

In the GCP platform LOGS tab

Have you checked Cloud logging UI or gcloud functions logs read ?

Thanks for helping! I solved it out by changing the logging.info to print, not sure why logging.info can not show anything in the UI..

Have you verified this document
for why you can't see logs? If this still doesn't answer your issue, I suggest you to reach out to google support.
